# PythonAnywhere.com Flask web app: no module named 'flask_app'

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I am new to Python Anywhere and I'm trying to set up a Flask web app I have already built. I followed this tutorial: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/

But when I try to access the site the log says this:

```
Error running WSGI application
2018-07-24 11:25:47,696: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_app'
2018-07-24 11:25:47,697:   File "/var/www/vdvaxel_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 111, in <module>
2018-07-24 11:25:47,697:     from flask_app import app as application  # noqa
```

I followed the tutorial step by step but still it doesn't work. Can someone explain me what is wrong?

Comment: Can you show us what your directory structure looks like, the command you're using to start the server, and the location from which you're running that command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to replace `flask_app` with the name of the file containing `app` and the app structure (routes, etc). Navigate to:

```
https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/{your_username}/files/var/www/vdvaxel_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py
```

Then, on the last line of the file, which is currently `from flask_app import app as application`, replace `flask_app` with the filename of your current app:

```
from my_new_web_app import app as application
```

Also, ensure that `project_home` in the `wsgi` file is pointing to the folder that stores your flask app file, along with any other folders such as `templates`, `static`, etc. To find the proper path, navigate to the folder itself and copy the "breadcrumb" navigation, just below the `pythonanywhere` logo.

Then save the file and access your site again.

Comment: That was the issue indeed :) my Flask app was called web-app.py... Didn't realize I had to change it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to answer without the details of your code structure.

1) Is your Flask web app in a file called `flask_app.py` ?

2) Have you uncommented and **updated** the block of code from section *Configuring the WSGI file*:

```
import sys
path = '/home/yourusername/mysite'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
```

so the `path` variable value really is the path were the `flask_app.py` file is located ?